# NMAKE: How do I force a debug build? [7ZIP]

Tags: build, nmake

The suggested way of building 7Zip is on the command line via the nmake command line utility. 7zip doesn't seem to come with a working visual studio solution.

I have seen invocations such as `nmake NEW_COMPILER=1 MY_STATIC_LINK=1` suggested for initiating a build using the various nested .MAK files.

Using this command line interface how might I force a build with debug symbols?

If there is no standard way to accomplish this via nmake, I'd be glad to receive help with regards to 7Zip in particular. I am much less familiar with .MAK than GNU make, and have thus far been unable to find something akin to a "debug target" in the GNU make sense in 7ZIP.

Answer (score 3):

To make a project that uses visual studio nmake build a debug output you need to edit the makefile and make 2 changes.

First you need to add /Zi to the list of flags used when compiling

```
CFLAGS = $(CFLAGS) -nologo -c -Fo$O/ -W4 -WX -EHsc -Gy -GR- -GF /Zi
```

Second you need to add /debug to list of options for the linker e.g.

```
LFLAGS = $(LFLAGS) -nologo -OPT:REF -OPT:ICF /DEBUG
```

I tested this on a different library, I assume there will be similarities here.

Answer (score 3):

**7zip** archiver gives great compression and performance results, but unfortunately have lack of documentation nor for building process nor at the entire code.
I know that the question asked 1.5 yrs ago but I hope to save someone time for digging around in the 7z.
To build 7z from sources you need the Microsoft Visual Studio and do following steps:

1. Start Tools Command Prompt for VS 2019
2. Navigate to sources folder `cd c:\sources\7z`
3. Invoke  `nmake /f makefile`

Otherwise you can convert MSVC 6.0 **dsw/dsp** files to modern **.vcxproj** format. Just open dsw file in the MSVC 2019 and it will do the conversion automatically.

The trick is that you need to navigate into project directory to do that. The 7z build system hard tied to relative directory structure and gets build parameters from top level main Build.mak file. 
So, if you need to modify build parameters for all projects it is enough to modify that file.

For `7z version 19.00`  you need to edit these lines in `CPP/Build.mak file`:

1. Add `/Zi` fag to line 
   `CFLAGS = $(CFLAGS) -nologo -c -Fo$O/ -W4 -WX -EHsc -Gy -GR- -GF /Zi`
2. Add `/DEBUG` 
   `LFLAGS = $(LFLAGS) -nologo -OPT:REF -OPT:ICF /DEBUG`
3. Change -O1 and -O2 for flags `CFLAGS_O1 CFLAGS_O2`

   ```
   !IF "$(PLATFORM)" == "x64"
   CFLAGS_O1 = $(CFLAGS) -Od
   !ELSE
   CFLAGS_O1 = $(CFLAGS) -Od
   !ENDIF
   CFLAGS_O2 = $(CFLAGS) -Od
   ```